# If $f,g$ are non-zero polynomials and $f$ divides $g$, then $\partial f \leq \partial g$.

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, field-theory

Mark the following true or false. (Here 'polynomial' means 'polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$'.)

1. If $f,g$ are non-zero polynomials and $f$ divides $g$, then $\partial f \leq \partial g$.

$\textbf{True.}$

2. Every irreducible polynomial has prime degree.

$\textbf{True.}$

3. If a polynomial $f$ has integer coefficients and is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$, then it is irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$.

$\textbf{True.}$ Since $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, then we can say that a polynomial, $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$, if it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$.

So I need to response to each of these questions with $3$ sentences or less. How would I do this for (1) and (2)? Also is what I have for number (3) enough or correct?

Comment: One question per post is preferred over three questions per post.

Comment: I grouped the questions together because I am having the same situation for all of them.

Comment: Neither 2) nor 3) is correct. 2) is incorrect because $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, so the only irreducible polynomials are those with degree $1$. For 3), consider the polynomials $x^{2} - 2$. This is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ by Eisenstein, but is reducible over $\mathbb{R}$ with roots $\pm \sqrt{2}$. I don't know what your notation for (1) means.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what 1 is asking. What does $\partial f \leq \partial g$ mean?

Comment: The notation $\partial f$ refers to the degree of the polynomial $f$.

Comment: @IvoTerek Thanks!

Comment: @AlexWertheim Thanks for your help. It has cleared everything for me.

Comment: For (1), if $f$ divides $g$, write $fh = g$ for some $h$, "apply" $\partial$ to both sides and use that $\partial(fh) = \partial f + \partial h$.

Comment: @IvoTerek I think that should be a less than or equal to sign.

Comment: Since $\Bbb C$ is a field, we'll have equality, no? Although yes, if we take polynomials over an arbitrary ring $R$, we'll have $\leq$, yes.

Comment: @IvoTerek $\partial( 0\times x^{100})=\partial(0)=0$ but $\partial(0)+\partial(x^{100})=0+100=100$

Comment: @avid19: the hypothesis is that $f$ and $g$ are nonzero :)

Comment: Ah. That case is a bit pathological, no? hahaha
I've seen a lot of people put $\partial 0 = -\infty$ for that formula to hold.

Comment: @AlexWertheim You are correct. It holds for nonzero polynomials.